# Determining the value of f(3) with a function that has 4 unknown variables

Tags: calculus, functions

This is a practice calc question I have been unable to solve, all I know is that $d = 5$. The fact the information is given as a rough answer rather than a definite integer is screwing me over.

Without giving away the answer how should I tackle a question like this?

$f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ where $a, b, c, d$ are integers.

$y$ intercept is $5$ and given that :

$\begin{align} &f(2) = -3 \\&40 < f(4) < 50\\&240 < f(6) < 250\end{align}$

Determine the value of $f(3)$

Comment: So $d=5$ and $8a+4b+2c=-8$, correct?

Comment: Yes :) At least that's what I got.

Comment: ...and what do you get if you try to express the inequalities in terms of $a,b,c$?

Comment: f(4) 40 < 64a + 16b + 4c + 5 < 50

Comment: f(6) 240 < 216a + 36b + 6c + 5 < 250

Comment: I have found the function using trial and improvement (although this is an improper way according to the question) — $2x^3-5x^2-2x+5$, so the value of $f(x)$ is 8.